# How to combine np arrays of different shapes together and separate by row

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, numpy

I am trying to combine several nparrays together. They are like the following:

```
 array1: [1]
         [0]
         [1]

array2: [ 3  4 14]
        [12  2 30]
        [ 3  4 14]

array3: [ 4  4 14]
        [12  2 30]
        [ 3  4 14]
```

What I want to achieve is:

```
      (array([3,  4,  14]), 1, array([4, 4, 14))
      (array([12, 2,  30]), 0, array([12,2, 30))
      (array([3,  4,  14]), 1, array([3,4,14]))
```

I am leanring python now and I have tried using `np.stack`, `np.concatenate`,
but neither worked. So I am wondering how to achieve the desired output.

Comment: these looks like plain tuples. `tuple(zip(array2,array1,array3))`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`numpy` functions such as `np.stack` and `np.concatenate` return `numpy` arrays.

However, your desired output is *not* a `numpy` array. The type is unclear, since you have not specified whether you wish to `print` values or store them in a `list` or `tuple`.

Below are some valid objects you can create from your inputs:

**Setup**

```
import numpy as np

array1 = np.array([[1], [0], [1]])

array2 = np.array([[3, 4, 14],
                   [12, 2, 30],
                   [3, 4, 14]])

array3 = np.array([[4, 4, 14],
                   [12, 2, 30],
                   [3, 4, 14]])
```

**Tuple of tuples**

```
res = tuple(zip(array2, array1.flatten(), array3))

((array([ 3,  4, 14]), 1, array([ 4,  4, 14])),
 (array([12,  2, 30]), 0, array([12,  2, 30])),
 (array([ 3,  4, 14]), 1, array([ 3,  4, 14])))
```

**List of tuples**

```
res = list(zip(array2, array1.flatten(), array3))

[(array([ 3,  4, 14]), 1, array([ 4,  4, 14])),
 (array([12,  2, 30]), 0, array([12,  2, 30])),
 (array([ 3,  4, 14]), 1, array([ 3,  4, 14]))]
```

**Single numpy array**

```
res = np.hstack((array2, array1, array3))

array([[ 3,  4, 14,  1,  4,  4, 14],
       [12,  2, 30,  0, 12,  2, 30],
       [ 3,  4, 14,  1,  3,  4, 14]])
```